# How to add a date range in Azure Data Factory data flow

Tags: date, azure-functions, date-range, azure-data-factory

### Working info

I have two different sources of data set so I have created a dataflow in data factory in which for first data(A) set I am doing some transformation and loading into sink,in another data set(B) similarly am performing some transformation and loading into another sink.

### Issue

Now I have some requirements in which there is date column DT_COLUMN_A(11-04-2020  01:17:40) in first data set(A)which needs to be compared with a date column DT_COLUMN_B(01-01-2020  16:32:00) in second data set (B) and store the compared output as a column in second dataset(B).

So I need the min and max(date range) of date column from dataset A ,apply it to min and max of date column to dataset B and find the dates which are matching in A and B and store it as YES if not matching NO.

### Code approach thought

Logic needed:

`if(min(DT_COLUMN_A) and max(DT_COLUMN_A) == min(DT_COLUMN_B) and max(DT_COLUMN_B) then YES else No.`

I am trying to achieve this in ADF data flow but unable to do it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that,but I didn't wrote purposefully,will restrict these from next time.

Answer (score 0):

To get MIN and MAX of a dataset in ADF, you will need the Aggregate transformation. Create new columns called MinA, MinB, MaxA, MaxB from each of the relative streams in your data flow using Aggregate. Set the aggregate function to MIN and MAX appropriately for each. Then, you'll be able to set an iif() expression afterward, or use a Filter or Conditional Split transformation that uses those stored min & max values.

Comment: I have created the min ad max for both the streams but while using the conditional split or filter how we can call min and max of different streams.
For Eg: iif(min(A) and max(A)= min(B) and max(B)) .i could not add the B column in the condition only min A and max A is present.

Comment: Join or Lookup first

Comment: I think calling max min from one column to other is possible

Comment: I tried using join but the problem is join is not giving any output.can you demonstrate by an example.. Basically I wanted to create a date range of a column in dataset A and use it in dataset B one of date column and compare that the dates which are in range and falling in dataset B date column and update a new column as Y If the date is falling in range and N If not falling in range.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get something similar to work using using a mapLoop() expression to first build an array of dates in a derived column transformation followed by a flatten transformation

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73453351/12592985

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).